# Startup disk not correctly identified?

Tags: macos, snow-leopard, startup

I have a Mid-2010 4 core MacPro. I mainly run 10.6.8, as I have a large software investment I'm not ready to abandon. As part of my migration to the present day OS, I have multiple startup drives, 2 PCI based SSDs.

When I am running 10.6.8 and attempt to reboot into 10.10, I see this;

[image]

Obviously *not* 10.10. So I attempt a boot and disc utility comes up offering the usual menu to restore the OS drive. When I quit the utility, I'm offered a choice of startup drives:

[image]

Now, the startup choices appear correctly, and boot me into 10.10. When running 10.10.2, I get a fast boot back to 10.6.8.

As it stands, I need 2 boots to get into 10.10 when running 10.6.8 prior. Why does the system still see any remnant of Lion?

Edit - perhaps the right question is - "Sagan SSD contains 10.10, why does this show as 10.7 when trying to boot into it while running 10.6.8?"

In response to the comment, diskutil list shows -

[image]

and it appears to me that when I try to boot Sagan SSD it's the recovery HD that tries to boot.

Comment: There is a lot going on here across multiple drives. Open the Terminal utility and update with the output of `diskutil list`. Off hand, I’d suggest manually setting the boot volume as 10.10 using `bless` and subsequently seeing if it boots directly.

Comment: Please add brand/model of the PCI-SSD-card(s) to your question.

Comment: It looks to me like 10.6 is only seeing the Yosemite recovery volume, not the main volume. Are you using FileVault volume encryption on the Yosemite system? If not, you might just need to turn off Core Storage management on the Yosemite volume.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to press the ["option" key during startup](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201255)? This will prompt you to select the startup disk if several are available. Set the system to boot into the one you will boot into most often, and if you want to boot into the other, press "option" when you switch the Mac on and wait for the prompt.

Comment: Yes. And that's an ok workaround, I suppose. Still, I'd like to solve why the drive isn't first recognized as 10.10, and shows 10.7 instead.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer: I wish I could tell you more, but from here I do not have the means to analyze your setting. I also still use 10.6.8 from time to time (Rosetta!), but on a different machine.